# profile java memory use on linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, memory-leaks, profiler

i have a socket server written in java, and i believe there is a memory leak. The i could not find anything in Netbeans' profiler, so i want to test it when it in deployed on my ubuntu server. How do i do this? What is an easy to install and use java profiler for ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out jprofiler. This works great.
http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [**Java VisualVM**](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html):

```
sudo apt-get install visualvm
jvisualvm
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you couldn't find anything with the NetBeans profiler, then VisualVM won't give you much more satisfaction as VisualVM is a standalone version of NetBeans profiler.

That being said, my recommendation to hunt **memory leaks** would be  [Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT)](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). In my opinion, this is simply the best Java heap analyzer you can get (even for money).

#### See also

- [Heap Dump Analysis with Memory Analyzer, Part 1: Heap Dumps](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/memoryanalyzer/2010/01/25/heap-dump-analysis-with-memory-analyzer-part-1-heap-dumps/)
- [Heap Dump Analysis with Memory Analyzer, Part 2: Shallow Size](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/memoryanalyzer/2010/02/25/heap-dump-analysis-with-memory-analyzer-part-2-shallow-size/)
- [Automated Heap Dump Analysis: Finding Memory Leaks with One Click](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/memoryanalyzer/2008/05/27/automated-heap-dump-analysis-finding-memory-leaks-with-one-click/)
- [Memory Analyzer Webinar](http://live.eclipse.org/node/520)
- [Getting Started](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/MemoryAnalyzer)

---

If you're strictly looking for a CPU and Memory profiler, famous commercial products include [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) and [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files.html), YourKit being my preferred one ([JXInsight](http://www.jinspired.com/products/jxinsight/) is another excellent product but not strictly a profiler).

#### Related questions

- [Please recommend a Java profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler)
- [What advantages have a commercial Java profiler over the free ones, e.g. the one in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490858/what-advantages-have-a-commercial-java-profiler-over-the-free-ones-e-g-the-one)
- [Open Source Java Profilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948549/open-source-java-profilers)
- [Eclipse Java Profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713940/eclipse-java-profiler)
- [Which Java profiler is better: JProfiler or YourKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163722/which-java-profiler-is-better-jprofiler-or-yourkit)

Comment: First SO question link is dead.