# visualvm vs JProbe vs JProfiler

Tags: java, performance, profiling, visualvm, jprofiler

There are multiple tools available for CPU and memory profiling, jvisualvm is fairly new among these.

Are there any comparison/benchmarking between these tools? Which tool is better than other?

Comment: +1. I wonder if somebody could provide comparison for YourKit

Comment: I would've liked to see an answer to this, but it's closed.  I believe visualvm is the newer replacement for jprofiler, both free.  I believe YourKit is commercial / not free.  I was looking for info on visualvm because the monitor graphics "jump around" when monitoring memory, I think due to sampling issues.  But I'll look a bit more before posting.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490858/what-advantages-have-a-commercial-java-profiler-over-the-free-ones-e-g-the-one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [YourKit Java Profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/index.jsp) and I was satisfied. Additionally, it is free for open-source projects (so I did not have to pay for it ;) )

Comment: With all the improvements lately to VisualVM, I am thinking that YourKit wouldn't be necessary.